# Grails RemoteLink and Cookie

Tags: ajax, grails, cookies

Hello (Sorry for my poor English),

I have a question which could seem simple :
I want to use remoteLink to set a cookie and use cookie value in response.
It's not efficient, because I must click Twice on the link to obtain correct behavior.
I suspect it's because cookie value is sent after template's call.

Here my gsp :

```
${agence.delegation}
<small>
    <g:if test="${cookie(name:'delegationId') == agence.id.toString()}">
        <g:remoteLink controller="docDelegationSite"
                      action="deleteDefaultAgency"
                      update="defautAgencyId"
                      params="${[delegationId: agence.id]}">
            Changer d'agence par défaut
        </g:remoteLink>
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
        <g:remoteLink controller="docDelegationSite"
                      action="defineDefaultAgency"
                      update="defautAgencyId"
                      params="${[delegationId: agence.id]}">
            Définir comme agence par défaut.
        </g:remoteLink>
    </g:else>
</small>
```

Here my controller :

```
def defineDefaultAgency() {
    def agence = DocDelegationSite.read(params.delegationId)
    cookieService.setCookie(response, 'delegationId', params.delegationId)
    render template: '/docDelegationSite/delegationCookie',
        model: [agence: agence]
}

def deleteDefaultAgency() {
    def agence = DocDelegationSite.read(params.delegationId)
    cookieService.setCookie(response, 'delegationId', null)
    render template: '/docDelegationSite/delegationCookie',
        model: [agence: agence]
}
```

So, how te be sure that cookie's value is sent before template's call ?

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is available from the next http request. I think you have not clear cookie behavior. Take a look at [http cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)